# Where is data directory in OpenShift 3?

Tags: openshift, openshift-3

Where data are stored which need a web service in `OpenShift 3`? Anyway how can I browser file system?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In OpenShift 3 there is no persistent storage provided by default. You will need to claim a persistent volume and then mount it at whatever directory you desire in the container for your application.

To view the contents of the directory, use `oc rsh` or the terminal window for a pod in the web console to get shell access, Then change to the directory to look in the directory.

To transfer files into the persistent volume, you can use the `oc rsync` command.

You can find a tutorial on transferring files in and out of container at https://learn.openshift.com

Comment: I tried to use rsync in windows 10 but it is not possible to push files from local or vice versa.